# How fast should miners computer generate work for ASICS?

Tags: asic, mining-software

how fast does the beaglebone black generate work? modern asic miners exhaust the nonce range in around 2-3 milliseconds.

say if it does exhaust in 2 milliseconds, and we need to keep the asics busy for 1 second, does it mean it needs to send 500 work items to the ASICS every second? what if it exhausts the range in 1 ms?

is the microcomputer capable of generating and sending that much data that fast? one work = 512 bits 1000 work items = 512000 bits

on uart the baud rate is 115200 bits/second

the work items data is approx 5 times more for every second. how is the data transfer handled?